# How to access duplicated columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following data in an excel file, with columns of same name.

```
Parts  Tanning Tanning Tanning
A          23     46      46
B          32     35      48
```

How can I access the data from the Tanning 2nd or 3rd column? Without using the column index number, but only using the header. Is there a way, without actually renaming the headers?

I am presently using the column index number, but the file is getting bigger by the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But while reading the file with read_excel, you can pas parameter `mangle_dupe_cols` as True ( it is False by default and By default pandas remove duplicate columns)

```
pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', mangle_dupe_cols=True)
```

and it will automatically name duplicate columns with prefix `<colname>.n` (n being count for duplicates for this column) as

```
Tanning.0,Tanning.1,Tanning.2, ....
```

Now you can access them as by putting  `.n` as prefix, where n is duplicate name count for prefix `Tanning`

```
df['Tanning.2']
```

Comment: I am actually getting an error when I try this print(df.Tanning.2)

Comment: Have added to answer, you need to access it with bracket syntax as it has special charater in key. Also, print your df to confirm if it named it like this.